# Changing background color in chat box with every message

Tags: html, css, stream, chat, twitch

I'm doing a chat to my stream, but I don't know how to switch the colors of each message, anyone have any idea how to do this in CSS and HTML? [Exemple](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m7waK.png)

Comment: I think your question is too general. Can you post a link? Not a photo, maybe the project itself. In this way we can see the css selectors and understand how to change background, text color etc.

However, usually it should be something like this:
`.test-box {
background: # 006dff;
}`
Replace the code `#006dff` with the color you want. The `.test-box` selector must be replaced with the one belonging to the chat box you want to modify.

Comment: Here it is! [link](https://codepen.io/crowegy/pen/NWabwLP)
Visualization will only appear on StreamLabs, that's where I'm programming my chat.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

You should change the following part of the code:

```
body {
  background: {background_color}; 
  font-family: 'Montserrat';
  font-weight: 700; 
  font-size: {font_size};
  line-height: 1.5em; color: {text_color};
}
```

Apparently the background part: `{background_color};` changes according to the background box setting you see in the screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/xfX5g.jpg

I've never used streamlabs, so I can't give you more info, but you could try watching this video: https://youtu.be/FXeamtuEUf0?t=142